# How to join/merge xml files into a single file and return it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I'm using the Last.fm API and I'm trying to get a lot of info about a certain user and returning it in xml. So, here's the call in my view:

```
<%= form_tag fetch_user_path, :remote => true, :'data-type' => 'xml', :id => 'search' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q %>
<% end %>
```

So, as you can see, it's expecting XML, and I'm correctly handling the callback using jQuery. Then, in my controller:

```
# fetch_controller.rb
def user
  username = params[:q].gsub(' ','+')
  get_info_url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getinfo&user=#{username}&api_key=#{API_KEY}"
  get_friends_url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getfriends&user=#{username}&api_key=#{API_KEY}"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml {
      begin
        @info = Nokogiri::XML(open(get_info_url))
        @friends = Nokogiri::XML(open(get_friends_url))
      rescue Exception => e
        if e.message == '400 Bad Request'
          render xml: { :error => 'User not found.' }, :status => 400
        else
          render xml: { :error => 'Connection to Last.fm failed.' }, :status => 500
        end
      else
        # Here, I want to render @info + @friends!
        render xml: @info
      end
    }
end
```

This way, I'm correctly returning the xml returned by `get_info_url`. However, I want to join that xml to the xml returned by `get_friends_url`. How would I go about that?

Following Ben Miller's answer, I'm getting a parserror on my callback. I think it's got to to do with both xml files containing `xml version`. And maybe the combined file does not? I'm seeing that the xml files are being concatenated, here's how they look using `console.log`:

```
Error: Invalid XML: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Combined>
  <UserInfo>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"??>
    <lfm status="ok">
      <user>
        # lots of info about the user
      </user>
    </lfm>
  </UserInfo>
  <FriendInfo>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"??>
      <lfm status="ok">
        <friends for="user" page="1" perpage="50" totalpages="2" total="96">
          # lots of info about the user's friends
        </friends>
      </lfm>
  </FriendInfo>
</Combined>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option it so convert the two XML object to a string and concat them, then wrap in a new root node.

Or you could do it with Nokogiri builder

```
def user
  username = params[:q].gsub(' ','+')
  get_info_url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getinfo&user=#{username}&api_key=#{API_KEY}"
  get_friends_url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getfriends&user=#{username}&api_key=#{API_KEY}"

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml {
      begin
        info_xml = Nokogiri::XML(open(get_info_url))
        friends_xml = Nokogiri::XML(open(get_friends_url))
        builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml_out|
          xml_out.Combined {
            xml_out.UserInfo {
              node = info_xml.at_xpath("//user")
              xml_out << node.to_xml.to_str
            }
            xml_out.FriendInfo {
              node = friends_xml.at_xpath("//friends")
              xml_out << node.to_xml.to_str
            }
          }
        end
      rescue Exception => e
        if e.message == '400 Bad Request'
          render xml: { :error => 'User not found.' }, :status => 400
        else
          render xml: { :error => 'Connection to Last.fm failed.' }, :status => 500
        end
      else
        render xml: builder.to_xml
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting closer!, but this is still not it. See my edited answer!

Comment: I updated the code sample.  The issue was that we were concatenating the full XML.  We needed to select only the node that you want.

Comment: It worked! Although you had a typo. You had `info_xml` 2 times, the second one should be `friends_xml`. Anyway, if you could answer one last question. Is there any difference between `at_xpath` and `xpath`? They seem interchangeable.

Comment: xpath will return all nodes matching the query, at_xpath returns first occurrence.  so at_xpath("query") = xpath("query").first

Comment: cut and paste strikes again... fixed the typo